# How to configure app.config file in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, configuration, app-config

I have my TCP port number, credentials and an IP address. How do I apply all of this to an `app.config` file to make it link to my database on another computer? I would like to apply it to my `app.config` file.

Comment: Pretty hard to say when we have no idea what your application does or why it would need a TCP anything.

Comment: Please elaborate as I'm pretty confused about what it is you're asking.

Comment: @JohnWu Hi this does not require to know how the what the application does..  Im researched before and it mentioned i need TCP port number

Comment: @KirkWoll I am asking how to configure the app.config file to link to the database i have on another server. Sorry for the typo in my question

Comment: Maybe check [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/416198/How-to-get-Connection-String-from-App-Config-in-Cs).

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=ip adresss->project location.;Initial Catalog=Title;Integrated Security=True"/>

Comment: ^Do i put it like this?

Comment: If reading from config file (which so far looks like duplicate of question *as asked*) is not the problem you are facing make sure to [edit] your post to clarify what you know and what exactly you have problem with. If for example you looking for help constructing connection string make sure to show how other similar posts and https://www.connectionstrings.com/ did not solve your particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="sampleConnString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**The key is the Network Library=DBMSSOCN; which tells your code to connect using TCP/IP**. 1433 is the defualt port used by SQL Server (assuming your database is SQL Server). TCP/IP is often the best for a firewalled environment.

Comment: Hi so if my TCP port number is different i put the port number there?

Comment: @Darren..provide some more information...your database? driver?

Comment: not really sure but i was only told that my TCP port is using a certain number  so how do i write for my TCP? My database is using SQL server but i am migrating it to mySQL

Comment: the port number i was given is 5000...

Comment: If you are connecting with SQL Server..then you can use above connection string..1) tcp:<servername>[\<instancename>],<port>......2)tcp:<IPAddress>[\<instancename>],<port> (try these options in Data Source value)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure System.Configuration is referenced in your project.

To add database configuration in your webconfig:
eg:

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
    </startup>
      <connectionString>
        <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="[Your connection string]"/>
      </connectionString>
</configuration>
```

To access it from C#:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"];
```

Comment: Hi Xela how to i check if system.configuration is referenced to my project?

Comment: Is it related to the connectionstring?

Comment: Nope, connection string uses similar functionality, but connection strings are for Database connection settings.

Comment: Hi i think there is a misunderstanding i would like to link my database from another computer to my project...

Comment: The other computer is a computer will act as a server which will be on 24 hrs

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer, you can check if it is referenced by expanding the references item in your solution explorer and looking for it.

Comment: How do i obtain the connection string for the other computer?

Comment: What database engine are you using sql server?

Comment: MySql or i have phpmyadmin in the "server computer"@Xela

Comment: and i am using app.config not web.config

Answer (score 0):

Specify data source in connection string with IP as below

```
data source=ip\sever instance
```